# Lambda Calculus Church Encoding Successor Function

Tags: lambda-calculus

I'm slightly confused by the successor function for Church numerals.

Written down in my textbook it is defined as follows:

$$succ = \lambda n. \lambda f. \lambda x. n \;f \; (f \; x) $$

Therefore incrementing a number $n$ by one works as follows:

$$ (\lambda n. \lambda f. \lambda x. n \; f \; (f \; x)) \; (\lambda f. \lambda x. f_n \; x)$$
$$ \rightarrow \lambda f. \lambda x. \; (\lambda f. \lambda x. f_n \; x) \; f \; (f \; x)$$
$$ \rightarrow \lambda f. \lambda x. (\lambda x. f_n \; x) \; (f \; x)$$
$$ \rightarrow \lambda f. \lambda x. (f_n \; (f \; x) $$
$$ = \lambda f. \lambda x. f_{n+1} \; x $$

where $n$ is represented as $\lambda f. \lambda x. f_{n} \; x$

My question is why would the following $succ$ formula not work:

$$ succ = \lambda n. (\lambda x. n) \; (f \; x)$$

I believe incrementing a number $n$ by one would work as follows using this formula:

$$ (\lambda n. (\lambda x. n) \; (f \; x)) \; (\lambda f. \lambda x. f_n \; x)$$
$$ \rightarrow (\lambda x. (\lambda f. \lambda x. f_n \; x)) \; (f \; x) $$
$$ \rightarrow \lambda f. \lambda x. f_n \; f \; x $$
$$ = \lambda f. \lambda x. f_{n+1} \; x$$

Does this formula not work because when I am performing $\beta$-reduction on the $x$ variable I am replacing the $x$ with $(f \; x)$ when I should not—possibly because it is bound by the inner abstraction?

Comment: That formula has an $f$ as a free variable on the right hand side. That seems problematic to me, even though I know nothing about this topic really.

Comment: @JohnHughes Thanks. I've noticed the $x$ is also a free variable. Probably two of the multiple issues with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here

$$
\underline{f} = (\lambda x. (\lambda fx. f^n x))(fx)
$$

$(\lambda fx.f^n x)$ has its own scope and $x$ in it is *bound* by it.

So

$$
\underline{f} = (\lambda x. (\lambda fx. f^n x))(fx) = \lambda fx.f^n x
= \underline{n}
$$

And yes, your function gives wrong result.